# Chain rule for the vector valued functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Suppose $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, $g:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$, then we have $D_j(f\circ g)(a)=\sum_{1}^{n}D_i f(g(a))D_jg^i(a)$.

How to show the above formula?

Comment: Do you know the chain rule in the form $D(f \circ g)(a) = D(f)(g(a)) \circ D(g)(a)$ where $D(\phi)(x)$ is the linear map approximating $\phi : \mathbb R^k \to  \mathbb R^l$ in the point $x$?

Comment: If we havs the chain rule as you mentioned,then $D_j(f\circ g)(a)=D(f^j\circ g)(a)$?

Comment: No. it gives exactly the formula in your question. Just represent the linear map D(ϕ) by the Jacobian matrix. A proof of the chain rule in its "linear map" form can be found in most textbooks. See for example Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" Theorem 9.15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the differential of composite functions, it’s easy. Take the differential of  $f \circ g$. It is the product of differentials. In this case, they are matrices (Jacobians), so the j-th partial derivative would be the product of the gradient of $f \circ g$ and the j-th column of the jacobian of $g$, that gives you your result

Comment: Would you mind explaining it in details?You mean $D_j(f\circ g)(a)$ is the $j$-th row of the Jacobian matrix of $D(f\circ g)(a)$?

Comment: Exactly. Can you see why?

Comment: $D(f \circ g)(a)$ is a $1 \times m$-matrix and $D_j(f \circ g)(a)$ is the $j$-th entry.

Comment: How to show that $D(f \circ g)(a)$ is a $1\times m$ matrix? Should it be a Jacobian matrix?

Comment: $f \circ g$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$, so its jacobian is a row vector (a gradient). I mean, a gradient is a particular jacobian matrix

Comment: @math112358 If $\phi : \mathbb R^k \to  \mathbb R^l$ , then $D(\phi)(a)$ is linear map $\mathbb R^k \to  \mathbb R^l$ represented by the Jacobian matrix $(D_j(\phi^i)(a))$ which is an $l \times k$-matrix.

Comment: @math112358 It is closed because it already has an answer.